# Unable to communicate with GDM-8341 DMM on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

The GDM-8341 DMM is not recognized as a VCP when you plug it into the raspberry pi, which means you can't use pyserial or pyvisa to talk to the instrument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was really frustrating, but this post here sent me on the right path:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=219232

sudo modprobe cp210x

sudo sh -c 'echo 2184 0030 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp210x/new_id'

(verify your vid/pid match 2184 and 0030 respectively)

After entering that "dmesg | grep tty" shows "usb 1-1.3: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0"

Now pyvisa works.

Hope this saves someone a lot of time.